# Why PhpStorm doesn't see files in /usr/bin?

Tags: mercurial, phpstorm, linux-mint, phpmd

I'm trying to configure PhpStorm 2019.3, my system is Linux Mint.

When I trying to set paths for utilities Mess Detector (phpmd), Code Sniffer (phpcs) and Mercurial (hg), PhpStorm is saying:

> error=2, no such file or directory.

Problem is that PhpStorm doesn't see these files, but see system files.

Utils are installed and placed in `/usr/bin`

```
~$ which phpmd
    /usr/bin/phpmd
~$ which phpcs
    /usr/bin/phpcs
~$ which hg
   /usr/bin/hg
```

Why can that be?

Comment: Do you specify just `phpmd`? if so -- try full path instead: `/usr/bin/phpmd`. I think it has to do with environment settings. Try launching PhpStorm from terminal and not by clicking on app icon. Will it work any better?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by removing phpstorm installed from Program manager and installing directly from official site.

Comment: I guess it's a permissions thing with respect to the wrapper