# PhpStorm Can't See Projects on USB on Linux OS [Zorin 16.3]

Tags: file, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, flatpak

We have just installed PhpStorm 2023.2.1 via flatpak from the Zorin 16.3 Linux OS "Software" package provider. The install ran smoothly and imported existing IDE settings.

Our projects and work related data (such as SSH Keys) are on a separate USB, attached to the computer. The computer has full user level access to these files via Nautilus.

PhpStorm can't see the USB drive, and can't access it in any way. PhpStorm can't open projects from the drive, can't import (drag and drop) PHP files from the drive into PhpStorm and can't re set up remote connections using SSH Keys (can't point to the SSH Keys on the USB).

## How can we get PhpStorm to recognise the USB media and access that data accordingly?

Previously on Windows PhpStorm had no issues accessing a secondary drive (E:) but can't seem to do this on this Linux OS.

p.s This is not the same as [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301246/why-phpstorm-doesnt-see-files-in-usr-bin).

### UPDATE

I have downloaded and used Jetbrains Toolbox app which works (running as `root` by the looks of it) but even then, loading PhpStorm installed by Toolbox the PhpStorm program is still unable to reach anything that is on the USB, unable to see the Drive.

*Arrgghhh, why is this so tediously complex?!*

Comment: This could be just Flatpak restrictions (where this app can have access). There were a few threads here when the IDE cannot see other tools (e.g. does not see git or node/npm) if using Flatpak (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73900621/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/64957896/783119).

Comment: @LazyOne this seems possible. I am trying to set up a more accessible install of PhpStorm using the links you post, but that [separately] is causing all sorts of issues [Java 17 is installed but PhpStorm is coming up with a fatal Java error on instal, etc. etc.]. If you can make this reference that it's an issue with FlatPak that can be the solution here. 

... I really would have hoped that Jetbrains would have had a smoother way of installing PhpStorm on a Linux / Ubuntu machine....

Comment: *"I really would have hoped that Jetbrains would have had a smoother way of installing PhpStorm on a Linux / Ubuntu machine...."* Toolbox App? https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/

Comment: @LazyOne I have used Toolbox but it download and installs PHPStorm and loads PHP storm ok but I still can't access the USB from the PHPStorm interface for any action. It simply can't see anything that isn't the main disk, however everything else can. Do I need to run toolbox as a root or something? I seem to have root access to the main disk currently on PhPstorm

Comment: Cannot help more than that I'm afraid. I'm not a "full time" Linux user and cannot advise much / only rather basic stuff.

Comment: I can confirm that Toolbox app provides the smoothest experience in Linux. I was using the official Snap release and I had problems opening certain files outside project root. The app provides native binaries and helps to keep them updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found through some luck and trial and error that the local folder;

```
/media/user/USB_reference
```

contains the USB data files and these can be opened and operated by PhpStorm.

I would like to be able to create a Symlink that I can put in /home/user/ that can link to a specific folder on the USB, eg. `/media/user/USB_reference/work`

Creating a Symlink (as root user in terminal) works well to make a new link in the /home/user directory that goes straight to the USB:

```
ln -s /media/user/USB_drivename/directory /home/user/USB_data_name
```

Comment: If `/media/user/USB_reference` does work, then I think the original question is missing some context. What path does Zorin's file manager display when you mount the drive?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it simply displays the drives name as a separate entity (rather like Windows displays other Disk Drives ) outside the current SSD drive name. This was my issue I think; I was looking outside the current SSD to find the drive when I needed to look inside the current SSD on a symlink. I'm not hugely familiar with Linux, yet....